# Postgresql query very slow when selecting a key from a JSONB field object

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

When including a key from the object stored in my `body` JSONB field the query is running ~100ms slower than without the field in the select:

```
SELECT id, 
       title,
       body->'_stats' AS stats
  FROM items
```

This takes about 105ms compared to only 5ms when the `stats` select isn't included. It doesn't seem to matter which key I return from the JSONB `body` object, they all significantly slow down the query. There are other keys from the body object I would like to include in this query, but each one I add increases the overall query time by ~50ms

The `body` field has a gin index and I'm seeing the behaviour in both PG v9.5x and v9.6.1

Any suggestions for alternative ways of returning jsonb object data more efficiently?

Answer (score -3):

[The first line in the Introduction of the JSON standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) reads (my emphasis):

> JSON is a text format that facilitates structured ***data interchange*** between all programming languages.

In short, JSON is good for sending and receiving information to/from other components of your application, but it is not a format native to databases in general and completely foreign to the relational data model and therefore not particularly fast however you want to approach it.

If you simply store and retrieve full JSON documents then there is no issue but as soon as you start manipulating JSON documents in the DBMS and speed is an issue then you should normalize your `json` data away.

Comment: I'm sorry but a patronising answer doesn't help anyone... I have very good reasons for using a jsonb field to store unstructured data - that is not the reason for the question. 

The surprising slow-down of the query could be due to the query engine having to load the entire body field before extracting the specific keys. A materialized view for the full query might be a work-around, something I'll try shortly.

Comment: I understand your frustration but the answer is not intended to be patronizing at all. You want to analyze _structured_ data (another term from the standard) in an environment that is optimized for _deconstructed_ data. JSON is pure 1NF while modern DBMSs operate most efficiently on 3NF data models. That distinction is something which more than a few programmers simply ignore so I see value in pointing it out.